# Modify values inside array

Tags: javascript

I create an array in this way:

```js
const [...mg_dx] = [0, 2, 4].map(index => buf.readInt16LE(index));
this.arrayMgDx.push([this.timeS, ...mg_dx].join(":"))
```

where I put a timestamp and values.

The result is like this:

```js
"-26416:393:333:574",
"-26336:393:332:573",
"-26296:393:332:573",
"-26296:395:333:574",
"-26276:396:333:574",
"-26236:396:332:574",
"-26216:396:332:576",
```

What I want to do is to change for the array the first value for every row (-26416,-26336,-26296...) starting from 0 and increment 20 for every row, like this:

```js
"0:393:333:574",
"20:393:332:573",
"40:393:332:573",
"60:395:333:574",
"80:396:333:574",
"100:396:332:574",
"120:396:332:576",
```

How can I do it?

Comment: Thought you should know, `const [...mg_dx] = array` is identical to `const mg_dx = array`

Comment: you are right :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `.map()` for that:

```js
const input = [ "-26416:393:333:574",
      "-26336:393:332:573",
      "-26296:393:332:573",
      "-26296:395:333:574",
      "-26276:396:333:574",
      "-26236:396:332:574",
      "-26216:396:332:576"]
      
const output = input.map((row, index) => {

  // array desctructuring here:
  // if we do sth like this:
  // const [first, ...parts] = [0, 1, 2, 3];
  // then `first` holds the first element of that array which is `0`
  // and the `parts` holds the rest of the array, which is `[1,2,3]`;
  // two techniques here: array destructuring and rest parameter
  const [first, ...parts] = row.split(':');
  return `${index * 20}:${parts.join(':')}`;
});

console.log(output);
```

- [Destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)
- [Rest parameter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters)

Comment: thank you for your answer, can you explain me about first and parts?

Comment: It's an array destructuring, I'll add a comment to explain

Answer (score 1):

You could replace every value using the following regular expression.

> `/^-\d+/`

```js
let values = [
  "-26416:393:333:574",
  "-26336:393:332:573",
  "-26296:393:332:573",
  "-26296:395:333:574",
  "-26276:396:333:574",
  "-26236:396:332:574",
  "-26216:396:332:576"
]

console.log(values.map((value, index) => value.replace(/^-\d+/, index * 20)));
```

Comment: Thank you! A question, with this method I select only the first value when it is negative?? Because I'm interested both (plus or minus)

Comment: @Jack23 Just modify the pattern: `/^([+-])?\d+/` to take an optional `+` or `-`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `slice()` and `indexOf()`

```js
let arr = [
  "-26416:393:333:574",
  "-26336:393:332:573",
  "-26296:393:332:573",
  "-26296:395:333:574",
  "-26276:396:333:574",
  "-26236:396:332:574",
  "-26216:396:332:576"
];

console.log(arr.map( (str, i) => i*20 + str.slice(str.indexOf(':'), -1) ));
```